# find one-character element in r and combine them if they are continuous

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe , I need to find one-character element in a row and combine them if they are continuous forexample:

```
v1    v2      v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8
m     i       l     k     200   gr.   low   fat
C     H       e     e     s     e     200   gr.
milk  l       o     w     fat   1.5   liter 0%
```

I want to change it to this:

```
v1     v2       v3    v4     v5    v6
milk   200      gr.   low    fat   NA
cheese 200      gr.   NA     NA    NA
milk   low      fat   1.5    Liter 0%
```

and it would be much appreciated if you could suggest a way which I could implement on big data.

Comment: something like `paste(df[1:4], collapse="")`

Comment: @jay.sf, there are not only in column 1:4 it can be in column 5:8 i need to find every one_charterer elements in each row and combine them ,i edit my question to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `nchar` you could detect cells with single character and combine them with `paste` in a row-wise `apply`. Use `unname` to get a somewhat clearer output.

```
apply(d, 1, function(x) {
  unname(c(paste(x[which(nchar(x) == 1)], collapse=""), x[which(nchar(x) != 1)]))
  })
# [[1]]
# [1] "milk" "200"  "gr."  "low"  "fat" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "CHeese" "200"    "gr."   
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "low"   "milk"  "fat"   "1.5"   "liter" "0%"
```

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(v1 = c("m", "C", "milk"), v2 = c("i", "H", "l"
), v3 = c("l", "e", "o"), v4 = c("k", "e", "w"), v5 = c("200", 
"s", "fat"), v6 = c("gr.", "e", "1.5"), v7 = c("low", "200", 
"liter"), v8 = c("fat", "gr.", "0%")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```